# Как вытащить данные из двух таблиц в одном запросе?

Tags: php, symfony

Получаю массив данных из таблицы **_liga** по полям **id** и **name**. Всё работает как надо.

Но мне надо одновременно еще вытащить данные из таблицы **_gr** по полям **names** и **bro**.

Как их правильно прописать?

```
public static function getLeagueById(Wb $wb, DbConnection $db, $leagueId) {
        $fromTable = $wb->getConfig("db_prefix") . "_liga AS L";
        
        $whereCondition = "L.id = %d";
    
        $parameters = $leagueId;
    
        $columns["L.id"] = "league_id";
        $columns["L.name"] = "league_name";

            
        $leagueinfos = $db->queryCachedSelect($columns, $fromTable, $whereCondition, $parameters, 1);
        $league = (isset($leagueinfos[0])) ? $leagueinfos[0] : array();
        
        return $league;
}
```

Comment: это что у вас за подобие ORMа ? какой-то фреймворк? указывайте в тегах тогда.

Comment: в целом подозреваю что `$fromTable .=$wb->getConfig('db_prefix') . "_gr as g" ON l.name = g.name` и `$columns['g.bro'] = "bro"` вас спасут

Comment: teran, добавил, но не работает

Comment: _одновременно еще вытащить данные из таблицы_ а какая связь между таблицами?

Comment: Покажите структуру таблиц или же укажите внешний ключ, по которому вы хотите сделать выборку. Но по факту, обычный join вам в помощь: `from ***_liga AS L inner join ***_gr G ON G.{foreign_key} = L.{freign_key | or ID | что-то, по чему вы join-ите} AND здесь могут быть еще условия, если первого выражения вам не достаточно`.

Comment: По правде говоря, для Symfony это не код, почему не Doctrine и ее QueryBuilder, там бы таких проблем не возникло + дока исчерпывающая.